# Groovy: Set dynamic nested method using string as path

Tags: dynamic, groovy

I have a path for an object within an object within an object and I want to set it using Groovy's dynamic abilities.  Usually you can do so just by doing the following:

```
class Foo {
  String bar
}


Foo foo = new Foo
foo."bar" = 'foobar'
```

That works OK.  But what if you have nested objects?  Something like:

```
class Foo {
  Bar bar
}

class Bar {
  String setMe
}
```

Now I want to use the dynamic setting, but

```
Foo foo = new Foo()
foo."bar.setMe" = 'This is the string I set into Bar'
```

Returns a MissingFieldException.

Any hints?

UPDATE:  Thanks to Tim for pointing me in the right direction, the initial code on there works great at retrieving a property, but I need to set the value using the path string.

Here's what I came up with from the page Tim suggested:

```
  def getProperty(object, String propertyPath) {
    propertyPath.tokenize('.').inject object, {obj, prop ->
      obj[prop]
    }
  }

  void setProperty(Object object, String propertyPath, Object value) {
    def pathElements = propertyPath.tokenize('.')
    Object parent = getProperty(object, pathElements[0..-2].join('.'))
    parent[pathElements[-1]] = value
  }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488689/how-to-retrieve-nested-properties-in-groovy

Comment: I was able to accomplish the task by building upon and using the getProperty method, I'll put the answer above since the comment section isn't very good to place code into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works correctly.

```
foo."bar"."setMe" = 'This is the string I set into Bar';
```

Without getProperty overriding you can achieve the same result using "${}" syntax for GString as the below code demonstrates

```
class Baz {
    String something
}

class Bar {

    Baz baz

}

class Foo {
    Bar bar
}

def foo = new Foo()
foo.bar = new Bar()
foo.bar.baz = new Baz()

def target = foo
def path = ["bar", "baz"]
for (value in path) {
    target = target."${value}"
}

target."something" = "someValue"
println foo.bar.baz.something
```

final println prints "someValue" as expected

Comment: Just a small addition to this excellent answer for others to avoid stumbling on this: You'll need to explicitly use `double quotes` for this to work, as GStrings(with expressions inside) are defined that way. But I guess all you groovy programmers already knew that :)